System does not go to sleep
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a Lenovo IdeaPad Pro 5 with an NVidia GeForceRTX 4050.
The system details says my firmware version is MECN63WW and kernel version Linux 6.8.0-36-generic.
Recently (within the last two weeks) my system stopped going to sleep after a set amount of time (I believe the setting related to this is under power-->power saving-->Screen blank). So, no matter how long my computer sits without being used, it does not turn the screen off or lock the computer.
I've searched to see if anyone else was having this issue and I haven't really found anything. Closest post I found was this post
I'm not really sure where to begin with troubleshooting this issue so any help or guidance would be really appreciated!

There is "sleep", where a process voluntarily surrenders the CPU for a time. There is "suspend" where the system saves itself to RAM and enters a low power state.  There is "hibernate", where the system saves itself to disk, and turns the computer off. "Suspend" requires a modern CPU, with controllable power states. "Hibernation" requires a RAM-sized, contiguous swap space.

From your comparison of sleep, suspend and hibernate I believe my computer is not suspending

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].
